# Understanding だと in this context?

Tags: grammar

> 折紙のうっすらと割れた腹筋や、美九の豊満な胸が右から左から襲ってくる。今の今まで肌に触れていた感触であるというのに、その姿を見**てからだと**、先ほどまでとはまったく異なった緊張と興奮が士道の頭の中で渦を巻いた。

I know だと can mean “if” but this meaning doesn’t seem to apply in this context. So how should I understand the bold だと? Can we omit it? If not, why?

Answer (score 1):

It serves to show the contrast between not seeing it yet and having seen it. It is necessary in this sentence because the following clause is describing that something has changed.

- 運動してから食べる "I will eat after exercising"
- 運動してからだとご飯がおいしい "Food tastes better after exercise"